# When I type something each letter is contains ^[ symbols in front of it

Tags: shell, grub, efi

I got to the login input in console mode on Ubuntu x86 EFI and when I type any letter it goes with ^[ symbols. For example, `artur` goes like `^[a^[r^[t^[u^[r`. What can I do to fix that?

Upd: It could be that console is UTF-8 while input goes as UTF-16 so the first 8 bits are the escape character `^[`... Or something like that.

Comment: check your setting of the TERM environment variable?

Comment: how can I do it without working keyboard input?

Comment: FWIW, in case this gives you and idea of something to look into, `^[` is one way to represent `ESC`. So this suggests to me that an escape character is being sent in front of every keypress.